# Table cell disable double click java swing

Tags: swing

[image]I observed that I can insert data into table cell by clicking single and double both.
Is there anyway to disable the double click functionality in the table cell??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer is to configure the cellEditor to start editing on single click

```
DefaultCellEditor editor = (DefaultCellEditor) table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
editor.setClickCountToStart(1);
```

That doesn't help, though - the double click will never reach the table because the first starts editing ;-) Reconsider the user interaction: typically, it's recommended that the second click enhances the action of the first, not that it does something completely different.

Comment: Thanks. But It does not solve my problem,you know. Is there any way to convert the double click action to single click?

Comment: @Rounak as already mentioned and logic tells you: you _cant_ have both at the same time, it's either the one or the other irrespective of how any tweaks and tricks. Anyway, from the screenshot I guess you are after something else then I understood - time for an sscce